# Cache Implementation for ExoPlayer in Android

Tags: android, caching, video, exoplayer

YouTube uses ExoPlayer in Android to play their Videos/Audios but you may have noticed , once you played a video , the next time it plays from the Cache, not from the server stream. I need to add this functionality on my Player, where should I do the customization to get that? OR anyone else (Except YouTube) did that? Proper link or suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Have you got any help on this?

Comment: Still can't figure it out !   :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41001057/2077869 This answer may help you if you havent already stumbled upon it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ExoPlayer **does not** support caching or saving the video. At least thats what [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/821) in Sept 2015 says.

You might be able to [grab the output buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360227/get-buffered-data-exoplayer) and write that as a file.

Safest method probably is to persist the video on your own in the background (means double bandwidth usage) and then do a check whether it was downloaded yet before starting streaming.